# overlay audio volume histogram over static image

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, spectrum

I'm actually working to a project for music video generation using ffmpeg.
I'd like to know if it's possibile to use ffmpeg itself or a combination of command line component under windows environment to make a visualization of audio spectrum (ahistogram ?) over a static background image like the one I found on the web:

[image]

Any ideas or coding tips?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i music.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]ahistogram=s=789x50:rheight=1[fg];[0][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-10:shortest=1,scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)',format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Not exactly what you want, there is no option to create bars as in your image, but perhaps this will be good enough. See the [ahistogram filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ahistogram) for more options.